# CGImage to UIImage doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uiimage, cgimage

I'm developing and iOS app for iPad and I use Grabkit in order to get images from Facebook, Twitter, Flicker and also the Camera Roll. To get the images from the last one, I need to convert a CGImage to an UIImage, but I'm having trouble with that. Is like if I didn't get any image, because when I use the UIImage later, the app crashes with this log:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 653]'
```

I'm using the following code to convert the CGImage:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
```

So this code doesn't crash, but when I use the image created, it does. What is happening? Is the code wrong?

Comment: is imgRef a UIImageView or simply a UIImage. You have to use imgRef.image if it's a view.

Comment: it means that the CGImage is NULL, check with a breakpoint

Comment: Here you can find all the code: http://ves.cat/hc33

Comment: By the way, imgRef is a CGImage created in the code you can see in this question: http://ves.cat/hc33

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use alloc init like `UIImage* myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:myCGImage];`

or you could try this:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
int size = height*width*bytesPerPixel;
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(size); 
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,width,height,bitsPerComponent,bytesPerRow,colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0,width,height),image);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];
CGContextRelease(context);    
free(rawData);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when implementing this solution.

CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Answer (score 0):

Great advice, helped me fix my memory leaking issue. Very important to free up allocated memory. When you do:

```
        unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc( dataSize );
```

also do this afterwards

```
        free(buffer);
```