# Error in getting CGImage from UIImage

Tags: ios

its work fine when we write:
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"];

but when try to make uiimage from nsdata like:UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
now when we try to get cgimage from img in draw rect then it gives badAccess.
if somebody know the exact way to write then please give me solution.
i use  CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [img CGImage]; in Draw Rect method of UIView.

Comment: provide some more code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576054/cgimage-to-uiimage-doesnt-work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756295/uiimage-from-cgimageref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use alloc init like:

```
UIImage* myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:myCGImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for converting `UIImage` to `CGImage` -

```
CGImage imageRef = imageObject.CGImage
```